# Can I connect to Vertica and HDFS in the same project using dbt core?

Tags: hdfs, vertica, dbt

I want to connect to Vertica and HDFS in the same project. I created a dbt project with command dbt init and try to connect to Vertica. It works but I don't know how to connect to hdfs to read data and load it to Vertica.

I need to read and load data from HDFS to Vertica database.
Is it possible?

Comment: What format is the data on HDFS? You can create external tables in Vertica out of data on HDFS in JSON, CSV, Parquet, ORC and Avro. Do that and run an INSERT .. SELECT using DBT

Comment: @marcothesane I have parquet files in HDFS. Could you send an example of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start reading the docu here:
https://docs.vertica.com/23.4.x/en/data-load/working-with-external-data/creating-external-tables/

An example for Parquet on HDFS:

Step 1:
Let Vertica infer the Parquet file's definition:

```
\a
Output format is unaligned.
\t
Showing only tuples.
SELECT infer_table_ddl(
  'hdfs:///data/tpch/region/'
||'3d5f4653-v_sbx_node0001-140498341713664-0.parquet' 
  USING PARAMETERS 
    format     = 'Parquet'
  , table_name = 'region'
  , table_type ='external'
)
vsql:infer.sql:7: WARNING 9311:  This generated statement contains one or more varchar/varbinary columns which default to length 80
create external table "region"(
  "r_regionkey" int, 
  "r_name" varchar, 
  "r_comment" varchar
) as copy from 'hdfs:///data/tpch/region/3d5f4653-v_sbx_node0001-140498341713664-0.parquet' parquet;
```

I would then suggest that you change the generated DDL statement to reflect the maximum lengths of `r_name` and `r_comment` (varchar(25) and varchar(152) , for example) before running it.

Once the command is executed, you can select from `region` as if it were a normal table.